# Preventing Screenshots and Screen Recording through DRMs?

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, cloudflare, drm, screen-recording

I am building a website which consists of videos that are structured like courses, for students to access. This will be a subscription based model. These videos are yoga videos, that are structured to flow like an actual class, and enables the student to customize based on how they want to practice, or to cater to specific needs. This is a broad overview of the website.

I am using Cloudflare Stream for storing and streaming the yoga videos.

The issue here, is that, a student can easily screen record the website while practicing, and that will be a major threat to our content. Moreover, they can just use the copied videos and never subscribe again. I have asked the same question on other platforms, and the first reply I always got was, "How are you going to prevent people recording it through their phones?". I know that this is something beyond my control and do not perceive that as a major threat. If I am able to implement screen recording prevention techniques, like a black screen that comes when they try to record, it will prevent a significant number of people from recording videos and accessing them in an unfair manner.

This is when I came across DRM and MultiDRM providers. I have spoken to a few organizations, like Gumlet amongst others, but they are a bit out of my budget given we're just starting out. I will invest in it if I don't have any other way to prevent screen recording, but I would like to know my options before committing to one.

Here are my questions, I hope anyone who has dealt with a similar problem can offer their advice, or anyone's thoughts for that matter.

1. Is there an easier way to prevent screen recording? I dont want the user to have to install any files that detect background applications, so is there a way I can implement something like that in when the website is running? I am working with ReactJS and NodeJS. Something that prevents the user from opening any other applications, and asks the user to close all applications while using the website?
2. Any other solutions/references I can implement to prevent screen recording?
3. Popular and friendly-on-the-pocket platforms that offer DRM protection? (My budget would be around $50 per month)